# Why is using the value of int i; undefined behaviour but using the value of rand() is not?

Tags: c++, random, undefined-behavior

If I don't initialise `i`, I don't know its value, but also I cannot predict the value of `rand()`.

But on the other hand, I know the value of the uninitialised `i` is between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, also I know the value of `rand()` is between `0` and `RAND_MAX`.

Why is using the value of the uninitialised `i` undefined behaviour but using the value of `rand()` is not?

Comment: The value of an uninitialized local non-static variable is *indeterminate*. The *pseudo*-random number returned by `rand` is deterministic if you know the current seed.

Comment: Even if `rand()` it's not generating a predictable number, it' s a certain number while running so the code below it is able to use it. This is different with uninitialized `i`.

Answer (score 7):

The value of an uninitialized variable is **undefined**. The return value of `rand()` is **well-defined as being the next number in the pseudo-random sequence for the given seed**.

You can *rely* on `rand()` returning a pseudorandom number. You cannot rely on any characteristic of the value of an uninitialized `int i`.

I looked up the C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999), which is the only standard document I have available, but I seriously doubt these things have changed. In chapter *6.2.6 Representations of types*, it is stated that integers are allowed to be stored in memory *with padding bits*, the value of which is *unspecified* but may include parity bits, which would be set upon initialization and any arithmetic operation on the integer. Certain representations (like e.g. a parity mismatch) could be *trap representations*, the behaviour of which is *undefined* (but might well terminate your program).

So, **no, you cannot even rely on an uninitialized `int i` to be `INT_MIN` <= `i` <= `INT_MAX`.**

Comment: But can we even actually rely on `INT_MIN` <= `i` <= `INT_MAX`? It doesn't have to crash, but it can very well, can't it? There are also other things that the compiler could mess with I guess.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: I would have to look up chapter and verse of the standard, but I'd say `int i;` is *defined* to allocate `i`, and thus there has to be *something* in there. I.e., it's the *contents* of `i` that are undefined, not the *existence* of `i`... then again, I usually steer *well* clear of any UB, because the compiler **is** at liberty to do funny things to you if you don't. ;-)

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: I *did* look up chapter and verse, and you're right.

Comment: It could even haven that `i != i`!

Answer (score 5):

The standard says reading from an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour, so it is. You cannot say that it is between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`. In fact, cannot really think of that variable as holding any value, so you couldn't even check that hypothesis<sup>*</sup>.

`rand()` on the other hand is designed to produce a random number within a range. If reading from the result of `rand()` were undefined, it wouldn't be part of any library because it couldn't be used.

---

<sup>* Usually "undefined behaviour" provides scope for optimization. The optimizer can do whatever it wants with an uninitialized variable, working under the assumption that it isn't read from.</sup>

Comment: I don't have the standard at hand, so perhaps you can shed light on this: Is `int i;` *defined* to allocate `i`? I.e., is the *existence* of an uninitialized `i` well-defined even if its contents are not?

Comment: @DevSolar I am not sure what the existence means if you can't read from the thing. I guess you can get it's address, and its size is known at compile time. But reading from it being UB really means anything can happen. An implementation could have a trap representation that triggers a signal, for example. I think here C++ differs from C, where the variable might store an unspecified value (IIRC, but my C isn't that good.)

Comment: Nope, C99 (which is the only standard document I have available) talks about trap representations as well. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DevSolar Good to know it. My C is a tiny bit better for that.

Comment: A definition `int i;` causes an `int` named `i` to exist within the relevant scope.   It is possible to do things to it, such as computing its address and assigning a value to it.   However, the act of reading its value before it has been initialised gives undefined behaviour.  That does not ONLY mean that the value is indeterminate.  The act of reading might cause any effect you can imagine, such as abnormal program termination, even before any attempt is made to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 2):

Value of `rand` is defined to be (pseudo-)random. Value of an uninitialized variable is not defined to be anything. That is the difference, whether something is defined to be anything meaningful (while `rand()` is also meaningful - it gives (pseudo-)random numbers) or undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, like others have said, is because the standard says so.

The act of accessing the value of a variable (described in the standard as performing an lvalue to rvalue conversion) that is uninitialised gives undefined behaviour.

`rand()` is specified as giving a value between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, where `RAND_MAX` (a macro declared in `<cstdlib>` for C++, and `<stdlib.h>` for C) is specified as having a value which is at least `32767`.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` uses an algorithm to generate your number. So `rand` is not undefined and if when you use `srand` to start the random generation you choose a value like 42, you will always get the same value each time you launch your app
try to launch this example you will see:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  srand(42);

  printf("%d\n", rand());
  return 0;
}
```

see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators

Answer (score 1):

Consider variable `x` in the following code:

```
uint32_t blah(uint32_t q, uint32_t r)
{
  uint16_t x;
  if (q)
    x=foo(q); // Assume return type of foo() is uint16_t
  if (r)
    x=bar(r); // Assume return type of bar() is uint16_t
  return x;
}
```

Since code never assigns `x` a value outside the range 0-65535, a compiler for a 32-bit processor could legitimately allocate a 32-bit register for it.  Indeed, since the value of `q` is never used after the first time `x` is written, a compiler could use the same register to hold `x` has had been used to hold `q`.  Ensuring that the function would always return a value 0-65535 would require adding some extra instructions compared with simply letting it return whatever happened to be in the register allocated to `x`.

Note that from the point of view of the Standard authors, if the Standard isn't going to require that the compiler make `x` hold a value from 0-65535, it may as well not specify *anything* about what may happen if code tries to use `x`.  Implementations that wish to offer any guarantees about behavior in such cases are free to do so, but the Standard imposes no requirements.